# Can I define a new command in Zathura?

Tags: zathura

Can I define a short command, say `dark`, that is equivalent to, say

```
set recolor-lightcolor \#002b36
set recolor-darkcolor \#839496
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to go for a key bind instead of command.

In case you want both commands available within a single combination then put to config ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc file something like:

```
map <C-l> feedkeys ":set recolor-lightcolor \#002b36<Return>:set recolor-darkcolor \#839496<Return>"
```

PS. Not sure why you need this, but if you also can just save it by default in the same config file so it will be loaded every time you launch zathura without additional moves. Just add your lines to the config file mentioned above.

PS. More detailed information about config file you can find [at official documentation page](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/documentation/)

Comment: Thanks! I need it because I like to use dark colours when it's dark and light when it's bright.

Comment: (So ideally I would want a toggle, but I imagine that would be hard.)

Comment: It doesn't work in newer versions, as I've test it.